# NW-SE diagonal sums of Riordan array

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, integer-sequences

I stumbled upon the sequence
$$1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0,...$$
which is the sequence https://oeis.org/A173432 and I was wondering what NW-SE diagonal sums of Riordan arrays are. I tried to deduce from the definition of the Riordan array https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riordan_array but I was not really succesful and google search gave me the impression that it simply means something related to the "direction of summation" but I am lacking a definition with gives me the integer sequence https://oeis.org/A173432.

Does anyone have the definition for me and how the sequence is derived from Riordan arrays?

Answer (score 1):

On the page for sequence [A112468](https://oeis.org/A112468), take a look at the example under "Triangle starts". Thinking of the entries in that example as having integer coordinates, draw straight lines of slope $-1/2$ through each "$1$" on the main diagonal and add up the entries on each such line. Those sums yield the sequence [A173432](https://oeis.org/A173432).

The fact that the matrix [A112468](https://oeis.org/A112468) is a Riordan array simply means that the ratio of the generating functions of any two successive columns in it stays the same. In this case, that ratio is $\frac{x}{1+x}$, and the leftmost column has the generating function $\frac{1}{1-x}$, so this Riordan array is uniquely defined by the ordered pair of functions $\left(\frac{1}{1-x},\frac{x}{1+x}\right)$. That's all there is to it.